# Distance calculation using MongoDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mongodb

I am trying to find the distance between two location P(x,y) and Q(a,b) in Java using MongoDB.

I am passing x,y that is latitude and longitude from my application and i get a,b as the nearest point, now what i am looking only distance between these two points. Somewhere i read geoNear support this, but i don't find Java code for geoNear, i got only commond which i can run on MongoDB command prompt.

Please let me know how to get distance calculation in Java Using MongoDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another user just asked a similar question regarding how to use the geoNear command with the Java driver.  Hopefully the answer will address your question as well.
[Calculate distance in Java Using MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224364/calculate-distance-in-java-using-mongodb)